# How to pass object from JavaScript to Windows Runtime Component C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I do have the following object **param** in JavaScript and I want to pass it to C# Windows Runtime Component for Windows Apps.

```
var param = {
        "url" : "http://192.168.101.224/DEMO/All/DemoService.svc/login",
        "requesttype" : "POST",
        "paramss" : {
            "userName" : "demouser",
            "password" : "abcdef",
            "domain" : "demodomain",
            "accessKey" : "12345"
        }
    }
.....
callWebservice: function (param, callBack) {
        try {
            service = new ServcieRuntimes.Service();
            service.callHttpService(param).then(function (data) { ... )};
```

In the C#, WinRT Component class, I'm doing like this.

```
 public IAsyncOperation<string> CallHttpService(string param)
    {
        return CallHttpServiceHelper(json).AsAsyncOperation();
    }

 private async Task<string> CallHttpServiceHelper(string param)
    {
        try
        { ....... }
```

But I'm getting

```
[object Object]
```

in C#.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you use `Newtonsoft.json` or `JavaScript Deserializer`.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for your quick response.How to use that? Should I use in C#? Is there any way to pass the full object ?

Answer (score 0):

Your C# code expects a (presumably JSON) string, you need to supply one

```
service.callHttpService(JSON.stringify(param)).then(function (data) { ... )};
```

You currently get

```
[object Object]
```

because that's the output of {}.toString();